# display values in XTemplate like textarea format

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs5

I am using the plugin rowexpander (grid) with the following template.

```
rowBodyTpl: new Ext.XTemplate('<div>'+
    '<div>'+
        '<b>Vegetables:</b>'+
        '<ul><li>{vegetables_types}</li></ul>'+
    '</div>'+
'</div>')
```

Displays vegetables types.

Items are sent to the server with a textarea field with each value separated by paragraph, creating a sort of list.

```
potatos
carrots
pumpkins
```

If I edit these values with a textarea, they are displayed in the textarea with the same format they were sent to the server (like a list).

However, with the XTemplate I just can display them on a single line.

```
potatos carrots pumpkins
```

I would appreciate suggestions to solve

EDIT:01-02-2016

FIDDLE: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/14se

FIDDLE (solved): https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/14sf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The XTemplate creates HTML, while the text area uses formatted plain text.

HTML does show line breaks from the code as a single space only. HTML line breaks are made using `<br>` tag.

So you have to replace `\n` with `<br>` in your template for the line breaks to show up:

```
    var rowBodyTpl = new Ext.XTemplate([
      '<div>',
      '<div style = "white-space: pre-wrap;">',
      '<b>Vegetables:{[this.replaceBR(values.vegetables_types)]}</b>',
      '</div>',
      '</div>',
        {
            replaceBR:function(text) {
                return text.replace(/\n/g,'<br>');
            } 
        }
    ]);
```

Comment: Thanks Alexander and Selmaril.

Comment: Thanks Alexander and Selmaril.The problem is that the textarea save the text in the server with chr(10) or \ n. I try to solve with CSS. Lack configure the <li> on all items. A edited my post with a fiddle with a ilsutration of the issue.

Comment: @josei I could finally fully test my code and found that XTemplates lack inline regexp support. I have moved the regexp into a function and it works.

Comment: Thanks Alexander a edited my last fiddle on my post with a strange solution. It seems, like you say, XTemplates lack inline regexp support.

Comment: I edited the second fiddle in my post with solution. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

I see two ways:

1. You can use tag `<pre>`. This tag shows preformatted text as is, with all spaces and new lines. (more see here: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_pre.asp ). Here sample: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/14il
2. You can make string array from vegetables_types string. It's best way I think. After it, you could use `<tpl for="vegetables_type">` statement (look here: http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1/5.1.1-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.XTemplate ). Here sample: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/14sa