# Displayfield with template

Tags: javascript, templates, extjs, extjs5

I'm trying to implement a tpl within a displayfield to display a list of data sent to the server from a textarea.

The same data is displayed in a grid with rowexpander plugin ([display values in XTemplate like textarea format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35119906/display-values-in-xtemplate-like-textarea-format/35125929#35125929))
Fiddle: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/14sf

I tried something like this:

FIDDLE: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/14t7
without sucess...

I tried every way I found to render a tpl unsuccessfully.

Display has a config **tpl** but it seems not work in my case...

I appreciate suggestions for resolving this issue

Comment: tpl config option is "inherited" from `Ext.Component`, but not used by `displayfield`. You could try `fieldSubTpl`.

Comment: Thanks Alexander. In my app console.says:  TypeError: Cannot read property 'dom' of null. I edited myfiddle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The displayfield also has renderer function. You can use it as in your grid:

```js
//var is just for illustration of the issue
var vegetables_types = 'potatos\ncarrots\npumpkins';

Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    width: 450,
    height: 200,
    bodyPadding: 10,
    title: 'Template',
    items: [{
        xtype: 'displayfield',
        fieldLabel: 'TPL',
        name: 'vegetables_types',
        renderer: function(value, field) {
            this.rndTpl = this.rndTpl || new Ext.XTemplate('<div><div>' + '<b>Vegetables: </b><ul><li>{[values.vegetables_types.replace(/\\n/g, "<li/>")]}</li><ul>' + '</div></div>');

            return this.rndTpl.apply({
                vegetables_types: value
            });
        },
        listeners: {
            render: function(field, eOpts) {
                field.setValue('potatos\ncarrots\npumpkins')
            }
        }
    }],

});
```

https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/14il

Comment: Thanks Selmaril. Works great. Only to realize better, why the following code segment: this.rndTpl ||

Comment: If it will be "this.rndTpl = new ..." or "var rndTpl = new ..", then XTemplate will be created on every call of renderer function (every time, when you use setValue of this field). It's something like cache. If rndTpl alrady exist, it's will be used, else will be created new XTemplate. Renderer always call at the Field component context, so, I just cached XTemplate as it's property. All clear?